# Using AdMob Mediation SDK implementation of Different Mediators

Tags: android, admob

Hey I want ask a question and I'll brief my question below.
I am using Admob in my project and it works awesome. but now I want to enable Admob Mediation. for this I implement my first mediator (MOBFOX) and when I implement this. I create an account on MOBFOX(or any other Mediator) and add this on my ADMOB account. so after Creating account on MOBFOX I download the SDK. and download the Adapter JAR file. I add the Adapter to my Libs folder so my QUESTION is that is this compulsory to implement the SDK of MOBFOX? (According to Google tutorial on youtube we only need to add the Adapter file and compile SDK file on gradle.build). if it is necessary to implements its SDK code then there is a conflict between both code ADMOB code and MOBFOX InterstitialAd. its only allow me to have one InterstitialAd OBJECT. and If I Implement the MOBFOX SDK code in my Interstitial Activity then where I will implement my ADMOB code. because I want ADMOB as my Primary and others Mediators as secondary. Please help my out from this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to directly use the MobFox SDK's API in your app. As long as you compile the MobFox SDK and adapter into your app and make sure your ad unit ID has MobFox in its mediation configuration, the AdMob SDK will automatically use the adapter to interact with the MobFox SDK on your behalf.

Comment: okay thanks for your response. I'll try this today. and have you any knowledge about AppLovin Mediator?

Comment: I did same for the AppLovin. (add its SDK and Adapter JAR file) but any of them send me a mail which is given below. 

I wonder how you have copied the Applovin's adaptor files. If you go through the links readme file, you would notice that the ApplovinAdaptor.java file must be in the com.applovin.mediation bundle path. For this, you can generate a JAR file by creating your own Android project and copying these file and exporting it.

Comment: Respected RedBrogdon can you please tell me about  the rewarded videos? Google Admob provides rewarded videos without implementing Mediation?

Comment: I don't know if I deserve the title of "respected," but I'm happy to help. :) All you need to do is implement rewarded video according to our guides (http://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/rewarded-video or http://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/rewarded-video), and create a rewarded video ad unit at http://apps.admob.com that has no mediation configured. You'll get rewarded video ads directly from AdMob, with no mediation adapters or other SDKs required.

Comment: A Senior is Always respected for me. :) . Now I have another issue that my admob account is now disabled by google admob due to invalid activity. I read all the document regarding Invalid activity but no condition is similar which is in my application. Is there any change to get my Account back? I'll wait for your kind response.

Comment: Account suspensions are not my area of expertise, I'm afraid. The most common cause is testing with live ads, but you should have gotten an email from AdMob with some kind of explanation.

Comment: So this means that We developers are the responsible for this account suspension? what we can do now ? Any suggestions for me to get my account back?

Comment: If I attach a new google admob account on my app to continue my app with admob. is it feasible for me? and from now I'll stop myself to testing with live ads. please guide me Respected Sir.